# Bing Desktop local image folder

Tags: desktop-customization, bing

Bing Desktop used to store images at `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\BingDesktop\themes\`. After the latest update to 1.3.395 the images are no longer stored there.

Did anyone find the new location?

Comment: A secret to finding them, is Picasa. It searches the entire PC for pictures when you install or change settings.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As of version `1.0.9.2` on 2021-08-02, , the location is:

`%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\BingWallpaperApp\WPImages`

or without the Variable:

`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\BingWallpaperApp\WPImages`

Comment: They seem to have moved again to C:\users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\BingDesktop\themes\

Comment: And moved again: C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\BingWallpaperApp\WPImages

Answer (score 2):

Bing Desktop 1.3.328.0 on 12/07/17

`C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\BingDesktop\themes`

Looks like only the last 8 are there, maybe they are being pruned.

Comment: You can get to it like this: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\BingDesktop\themes`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. Solution

If you have Picasa, then:

Start it and search for an image and when find it right-click and select "Locate on Disk"

If you don't have Picasa, then:

1. Download [Folder Change View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/folder_changes_view.html)
2. Before starting Bing, run Folder Change View and select Drive C for monitoring
3. Now start Bing and now every wallpaper that is saved on your pc will be shown there

Comment: Quick note: Don't use a comma between the URL and title of a Markdown link. A space will do.

Answer (score -2):

If you search for Bing with Windows 10 Explorer, it will only find a link (.lnk)

If you use 'Free Commander':

- use special folder shortcuts to got to 'local'
- search for 'Bing' from here
- it will find the 'Bing' folder and you can open the folder

There is a Bing themes folder here:

- (C:\Users\%MYNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\BingDesktop)